# finding a file created with C++

Tags: c++, macos, path, osx-lion

I am learning to program a bit in C++. I am working on Mac OS X and trying to create a file with some data by writing this code:

```
ofstream myfile;     
myfile.open ("primescount.csv");     
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";     
myfile.close();
```

In the tutorials I use I find that the file thus created can be found in the same directory as the executable. However, when I look there, I see nothing.

So my question is: where can I find the file (primescount.csv)?

I hope you can help, although this may not be the most inspiring question for you guys.

Regards, Lars

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as posted.  Can you show a full complete example?  How are you running your program?

Comment: What do you use to compile the code and run the executable?

Comment: You will find it in the directory which was set in the environment when it was executed. This depends on how you execute it.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in the directory you're executing from?

Comment: The tutorials are incorrect. The file will be in the *current working directory* established when the executable was started. Are you using **Xcode** to run your program?

Comment: Is the file being created properly? Add a check `myfile.open("file.txt"); if(!myfile.is_open()) { std::cout<<"file not open"; }` If it isn't open, you probably lack permissions in the directory it is trying to create the file in.

Comment: Hi guys, I compile the program by clicking the run/build button of Xcode. I am even pretty sure that the file exists, since I tested its existence by adding some code that opens and reads the file. Only I cannot see it and therefore not open it in an editor......

Comment: possible duplicate of [File creation in C++ on Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098836/file-creation-in-c-on-xcode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file will be found in the current directory—this *may*
be the same directory as the executable, but usually, it's not.

For Xcode, the current working directory defaults to the build-target folder of the Run target, which is usually buried in the depths of a temp-folder. You can change what the current working directory is at startup by doing the following:

1. Click on the Project box to the right of the STOP button on the main toolbar
2. Select Edit Scheme
3. Select the "Run" sub scheme in the left pane list.
4. Select the Options tab,
5. Check the "Use Custom Working Directory" checkbox
6. Set the working directory to some place you *know* (like your project root folder or even your home folder, usually `/Users/YourUserName`).

Your file should be created in the directory you specified, provided you have permissions to create the file in that folder, which you will by default if it is under your user folder.

Comment: Ok thanks. It now complains, giving the following message: 

The working directory "Users/MyUsername" for scheme "primes" doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok I needed to add the extra / in the beginning. It seems to be solved :-) Thanks!

Sorry I can't be more challenging :)

Answer (score 0):

The file is created in the 'working directory'. Different IDEs and execution environments set the working directory differently. If you're using Xcode then when you start debugging the working directory is set to whatever you have set for the current scheme:

[screenshot on google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+working+directory&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS392US393&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nE02Ue-hBIeX0QHBj4DwCA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1496&bih=806#imgrc=12S-BkbZXsZwfM%3A%3B9Mu5VMPrly0YWM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fchaosinmotion.com%252Fblog%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F01%252Fsettingimage.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fchaosinmotion.com%252Fblog%252F%253Fpaged%253D2%3B600%3B407)

If you're running the program from the command line then the working directory is the directory you are 'in'. I.e., the command `cd` sets the working directory. You can use the command `pwd` to print the name of the working directory.