# How to connect text files to stdouts in c

Tags: c, stdout, printf

I'm teaching myself c and I'm stuck on a practice question:

"Write a program that uses fprintf to print to stdout. Note that stdout is not a file name, but an existing file that always gets opened."

The problem is that I have everything set up, but I can't figure out how to attach my text.txt file so it opens during each run. I'm using Xcode.

Here is my code so far, it's an outline based on the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char  s[ 100 ];

fp = fopen( "text.txt", "r" );

if (!fp)

    fprintf( stderr, "I couldn't open the file.\n" );

else
{
    fgets( s, 100, fp );

    printf( "%s", s );
}

printf( "\n\nPress [ENTER] to exit the program.\n" );
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Any insight is appreciated! I know I skipped a step somewhere. Urgh.

Comment: You know everything you need to know, but you don't know it. :) Check out how you're showing the error message about being unable to open the file. See how you're sending output to the "existing file that always gets opened" called `stderr`? You can do the same for `stdout` (instead of using `printf`, say).

Comment: Are you trying to rewire `stdout` so i hammers *your* text file rather than the default output stream (in effect incorporating redirection without reliance of the shell)? If so, see [`freopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen). It may do what you seek.

Comment: @prprcupofcoffee hmmm... I'm not sure that I know what you mean. You're saying that my if and else statements should be switched so my printf is first? I just figured I had to take my text file and put it in the folder, and it would automatically connect to open on a run, but instead the output is repeatedly giving me my stderr msg. I just want to know how to make it open rather than giving me the error msg. (I'm so slow with coding, sorry!)

Comment: @pixelpinch The file you're attempting to load, "text.txt", must be in the current working directory. When run from Xcode, the default working directory is the build folder, which is almost certainly *not* what you want. Without a qualified path name, the folder where your data file is located must be the current working directory. [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14098917/1322972) can help you understand how to set that up in Xcode. Just make sure your data file is in the folder you establish as the startup working directory.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks Craig! I'll give that a try and see if I can wrangle it into working.

Comment: @WhozCraig
My current output is "

Press [ENTER] to exit the program.
"
That's all I'm getting. My file is in the current working directory but still isn't showing up in any way. Given, I don't know what to be looking for - all I know is it isn't opening when I run it. Is there not a way to connect text.txt to my C file so it recognizes it needs to be opened, aside from putting it in the directory?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm looking through the info and it says that the text.txt file is:
Current Branch: Master,
Version: Not yet committed,
Status: Added,

If that helps.

Comment: @pixelpinch The answer linked is specific to setting up Xcode to start your process from a specific working folder. Without a qualified path name the file you're attempting to open by name-only must reside in that folder. The output you linked in your last comment indicates that the file is opening correctly (assuming you still wanted to open in read-only mode and have not incorporated the `"a"` mode as suggested in the answers below). I can't really explain how to establish the CWD when running from Xcode better than I did in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters,

```
fp = fopen( "text.txt", "r" );
```

opens the file in read mode, you probably want [append mode](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).

```
fp = fopen( "text.txt", "a" );
```

Next

```
printf( "%s", s );
```

will write to the stream stdout (and just because stdout is [well standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), it's probably not a good idea to refer to you "file where I always append output to" as stdout).  If you want the same output to go to fp, you need

```
fprintf(fp,"%s", s );
```

Comment: This improved it, thanks so much!
However, I still have no idea what I'm looking for in terms of the actual text file opening when I run it. Would it open? I've never written this kind of action before.

Comment: Have you followed the link to the fopen man page?  Quoting: `a - 
Open for appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist. The stream is positioned at the end of the file.`  So you specify some filename, if the file exists the output will be appended to that file, if that file does not exist (eg because you erased it, or it's the very first time your program runs) the file will be created.  Just try it out and watch its behavior, it should be quite clear what's going on once you see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The program you've written above already uses `fprintf` to print to stderr, which is also an "existing file that always gets opened."

As a side-note you should close the `text.txt` file-pointer after you use it with `fp.close()`.