# Appending strings to a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I have always had problems with file output and input in C++. For some reason i just cant understand it. But I have a problem (yes, for a class.. I know. I already feel bad but the professor isn't much help) on this function I'm working on for a menu.

Here's what i've got so far.

```
void addName(){
string name;
ofstream outfile;
cout << "Please type a name you would like to add:";

outfile.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::app);
cin >> name;
outfile << name;
cout << "Name added!" << endl;
}
```

I call this into my `main` thing. Sorry for my amateur-ness.

The question is how can I append "names" to my `file.txt`?

Screenshots :

http://gyazo.com/24fe08435a6a1427de619892f2b28d1f

http://gyazo.com/4aa58fee549aba6771bcbc6811542f91

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: That's the weird part, it runs fine but does not actually add the name to the file. @DrewDormann

Comment: Or you are looking at the wrong file, perhaps.

Comment: added 2 screenshots for reference. @DrewDormann

Comment: Try calling outfile.close() before closing brace.

Comment: @MateuszKacprzak , I heard that is unnecessary. And still didn't fix it.

Comment: @MateuszKacprzak no need, the destructor will close the file. It compiles and works fine: http://ideone.com/mEJL27 (and works ok on my machine). Check that you open the correct file, do a test `if(!outfile) std::cout << "didn't open the file\n";`

Comment: @NealC Out of curiosity, are you running this from the Xcode debugger when you're testing it?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. But I don't know how else to run it tbh...

Comment: You don't need spaces between names?

Comment: @NealC [Read this please.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098836/file-creation-in-c-on-xcode/14098917#14098917)

Comment: @WhozCraig you are a genius. Thank you. I'm quite on my own for having a Mac in a class full of PCs.

Comment: @NealC I came from a VStudio world, and frankly it spoiled me rotten. Xcode has a ton of quirks you slowly figure out over time. Glad it helped. There are other ways to do it but that is the easiest to explain and pretty direct. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking at the wrong file. Your file will be located where your source code is. And not in the `Debug` or `Release` folder.