# ERROR: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68) FIX: PLACE THE IN AND OUT FILES IN THE WORKING DIRECTORY OF THE PROJECT

Tags: c++, c

I get this error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)

on the following line:

```
   while(fscanf(f,"%d", &a[x])==1)
```

1st time trying to do my class homework in Xcode, used code blocks before and managed to run this same code on it, any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <cstdio>
int a[1001];
int main()
{
   int aux1,aux2,aux3,x=0;
   FILE *f,*g;
   f=fopen("1.in","r");
   g=fopen("2.out","w");
   while(fscanf(f,"%d", &a[x])==1)        //HERE
   {
       aux1=a[x];
       aux2=0;
       aux3=0;
       while(a[x]!=0)
       {
           aux2=aux2*10+a[x]%10;
           a[x]=a[x]/10;
           aux3=aux3*10+9;
       }
       if(aux3-aux2==aux1)
           fprintf(g,"1 ");
       else fprintf(g,"0 ");
       x++;
   }
   fclose(f);
   fclose(g);
return 0;
}
```

To find out if you put the in and out files in the working directory you must try to print the read numbers in a terminal, if it doesn't print anything then I your .in and .out files are outside the working directory.

Debug:

After this line :

```
fscanf(f,"%d", &n);
```

do:

```
printf("%d", n);
```

if it prints the number well, guess your files are in the working directory, just make sure .out and .in are in the same directory and that's it.

Comment: Most probably `&a[x]` is the cause. Check if `x` is a valid index. Don't post images of code please, provide a [mcve] with well formatted code as text in your question instead.

Comment: Please put the code in text not in a picture

Comment: It would have been easier to simply copy and paste your code in the posting section than to actually convert your code to an image.  I don't know why so many first-time posters go the circuitous route of creating images of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie simplified and mobile versions of UI (for simplified view of Edge and other browsers and for tablets\phones). It doesn't provide any tools for formatting\editing. They have no idea how to do add code manually  (and some input methods don't allow it, removing spaces).

Comment: My OCR image-to-text-to-speech is having trouble with the linked image.  My guess is that `x` is out of range.  What are the inputs?

Comment: When you see an address at zero or really close to it, go looking for `NULL`-or-`nullptr`-ed pointers. Rather than posting a picture of the code, back up the code and hack out as much of the code as you can while still having a program that runs and exhibits the bug. Usually the reduced noise allows you to see and fix the bug. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Comment: Also test the results of function calls to make sure they succeeded. No point using the result of the function if the function failed. That just leads to bugs.

Comment: @MacCPP. Put that into question, copy-paste so it would retain formatting. Use `{}` button in editor (if you don't see it, switch to desktop\full mode of page). For in-line code you can use \` as quotes.

Comment: As you can see, code looks like garbled nonsense in a comment. Prefer to add it directly to the question with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63799977/edit) where it can be intelligently formatted.

Comment: Done, got it, it kept giving me an error.

Comment: So, what is `x` when you notice the error?

Comment: After `f=fopen("1.in","r");`, add `if (f==NULL) { printf("1.in failed to open"); return -1; } ` and see what happens.

Comment: @MacCPP You didn't check to see if you actually opened the file successfully.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't know, I get the error when compiling it, down below it says   x= (int) 0

Comment: @user4581301 now it outputs in terminal 1.in failed to openProgram ended with exit code: 255

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't, since it's my first time I did it just as I would've done on CodeBlocks, added in the same folder as the cpp, the 1.in and 1.out

Comment: @MacCPP -- Do not write code assuming things work, file exists where you think they are placed, etc.  Check if `fopen` returns NULL.  If it does, then the whole reason why your program doesn't work is basically solved in terms of why you are getting a crash.

Comment: OK. For any number of reasons, probably going to turn out to be your IDE runs the program from a folder you aren't expecting and doesn't contain the 1.in file, the 1.in file failed to open.

Comment: Next step for me would be to find out what folder your IDE is running in with [`getcwd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) or the [Windows version `_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=vs-2019)  and then move 1.in to that folder.

Comment: @user4581301 Yup, exactly, I think I placed them wrong, it runs from another folder, different from CodeBlocks I think, so I will make some research to find out where I should place my .in and .out files

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yup, NULL

Comment: Informational reading: [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

Comment: At the risk of sounding self-serving, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14098917/1322972).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I placed 1.in and 1.out outside the working directory, to fix this had to go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme>Run>Options and set a custom "Working Directory" where I placed the 1.in and 1.out files. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Just a note: The biggest problem isn't that you failed to open the files but that you don't check if the files are successfully opened. If you had checked that and printed an error message, you would have figured this out very quickly.

Comment: Yup, true, good to check in the future

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that  you actually opened 1.in file by checking what `open()` had returned. Make sure that you do not go outside of array bounds, if x reach 1001, something bad may happen, it's an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Gives this error, what else I should include?

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'open'

Comment: @MacCPP `fopen ()` in your case. Is sets `errno` and may return EINVAl  , i.e. NULL. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html If it does either file isn't where you expect it to be or you have no access to it.

Comment: Yeah apparently I placed 1.in and 1.out in the wrong folder, have to find out where I have to place them now, it's different than codeblocks